# Creating custom event pool in javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I have some client side logic (I have a little 3d world where objects interacts), and I would like to add some events listener like this:

```
 window.addEventListener("myAmazingEvent", () => {doSomethingAmazing})
```

How can I implement this eventListener to my own class? Like:

```
    class Person {
       construcor() {

       this.listener = new SomeJavascriptEventListener() 
    }

    crouched() {

       this.listener.call("onCrunch")
    }


const a = new Person()
a.addEventListener("onCrunch", () => {a.startSinging()})
```

What javascript **built in** classes can provide this behaviour to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's standard library doesn't have any direct event emitter support. There are **lots** of event emitter libraries you can find with a search, but none of them is built-in.

You can:

- Use one of the pre-built, pre-tested event emitter libraries that already exist (look for "event emitter" or "publish/subscribe" or "pub/sub").
- Use something built into the environment you're running your code in. Node.js has an [`EventEmitter` class](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#class-eventemitter). On browsers, you could create a DOM element that you keep in your class instance (no need for it to be in the document) and use it to store event listeners, then use `dispatchEvent` to send events to it. (Though that's not really simpler than the next option.)
- Build your own by maintaining an array or `Set` of event listeners for each event type that you loop through and call when you need to emit an event.

All three are viable options.

But to give you an idea, a class with very basic event handling looks like this:

```js
class Example {
    #eventHandlers = {
        "some-event": new Set(),
        "another-event": new Set(),
    };

    on(eventName, handler) {
        const handlers = this.#eventHandlers[eventName];
        if (!handlers) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid event name "${eventName}"`);
        }
        handlers.add(handler);
    }

    off(eventName, handler) {
        const handlers = this.#eventHandlers[eventName];
        if (!handlers) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid event name "${eventName}"`);
        }
        handlers.delete(handler);
    }

    #trigger(eventName, ...eventArgs) {
        const handlers = this.#eventHandlers[eventName];
        // assert(!!handlers);
        for (const handler of handlers) {
            try {
                handler(...eventArgs);
            } catch { // (Add (e) if your environment doesn't support optional catch bindings)
            }
        }
    }

    doSomething() {
        // In this example, "doing something" triggers the `some-event` event
        this.#trigger("some-event", "something happened");
    }
}

const e = new Example();
e.on("some-event", (msg) => console.log(`Handler one: received "${msg}"`));
e.on("some-event", (msg) => console.log(`Handler two: received "${msg}"`));
e.doSomething();
```

That uses relatively modern things (private fields, optional catch bindings), but you can adapt it as needed.

There are a *dozen* or more ways to skin this cat. Cross-talk between nandlers, cancelling events, passing in some kind of `Event` object, etc., etc., etc. But the fundamentals are:

- Registering handlers (`on` in the example)
- Unregistering handlers (`off` in the example)
- Triggering events (`#trigger` in the example)

Comment: Nah, I though there is something built-in, thanks for your time. Have a nice day.